# adavantages and/or disadvantages oof mutable and immutable classes

Tags: java

I have read many articles comparing muable and immutable classes in java. **I have also read that immutable classes are easier to understand than mutable once** (to the user of course).

**Why it is so..?** Actually I think that mutable classes show real problems more precisely than immutable once and developer does not have to carry an overhead of creating new objects every time.

please help me with that

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you comparing mutable and immutable classes in Java 5? Also, why the C# 4.0 tag?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza He's spam-tagging but didn't manage to get the actual relevant one of `oop`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Perhaps OP's comparing them in C# 4.0 and the Java 5 tag is nonsense. Or both languages are relevant. Or neither. Or perhaps OP just didn't choose the best tags :-)

Comment: I wrote c# because it was suggested to me. My question is not regarding any version it is just mutable vs immutable classes